# Routing Error uninitialized constant when I create a new action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I know it is a typical problem. But I was just trying the routing in rails and I get this error:

```
uninitialized constant UsersController
```

And I don't know well where is the problem.
The resume of my app is a simple application of a library, where users can book books and see the books they've booked. 
Here is my routes.rb

```
Brickstest2::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :books

  root "pages#home"    
  get "home", to: "pages#home", as: "home"
  get "inside", to: "pages#inside", as: "inside"


  devise_for :users

  namespace :admin do
    root "base#index"
    resources :users
  end

  resources :books do
    get :book_a_book, :as => "reserve"
  end

  resources :users do
    get :booked_books, :as => "reserved", :on => :member
  end

end
```

Actually When I do rake routes I get:

```
reserved_user_path
    GET  /users/:id/booked_books(.:format)   users#booked_books
```

And in users_controllers.rb I have:

```
 def booked_books
    @user = User.first(params[:user_id])
    #return unless @user == current_user
    @books = Books.where(:user = @user)
  end
```

The link to booked_books:

```
<%= link_to "My books", user_reserved_path(:user_id => current_user.id)%>
```

And finally my users/booked_books.html.erb:

```
<h1>My books</h1>
<%= @books.each do |book|%>
    <p><%= book.name %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you declared a controller for your `User` resource that subclasses `ApplicationController`?

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
```

Note that the precise naming convention for a plural resource route for the `User` model is `UsersController` (note the `s`). I'm guessing that you've named your controller class `UserController`, which won't work for your use-case.

**UPDATE**:

Since you've declared a controller namespace, you'll want to declare your controller class like so:

```
# app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb
class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController
```

This should resolve any `uninitialized constant UsersController` errors involving your namespace.

Comment: Actually, with this, I realized that I didn't really have # app/controllers/users_controller.rb
Because I'm using devise. I was creating the action in # app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb

Comment: If you're using Devise, you'll still need to create your own UsersController. Devise merely [extends the functionality](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started) of resources – it doesn't replace it altogether.

Comment: Did this help resolve your question? If so, please consider [upvoting/accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).